# Clear the contents of a permanent register or yank to it without appending to it?

Tags: register

I have a permanent register `"T`  and it's filled with something already.  When I yank something else into it, it's appended to the register.

I'd like to clear out just that one register so I can yank something fresh to it without appending to it.

My command for yanking is `"Ty`...

I've already tried several things in ex mode like:

`:call setreg('T', [])`

`let @T=''`

And it doesn't go away....

Comment: But you know that register `T` is the same as register `t`, but lower case replaces, while upper case appends? You don't have to clear it, just use `"ty` or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No I didn't know that... :(  all I knew is that if you use `"Ty` it will persist between closings vim.

Answer (score 2):

As Philippos [pointed out in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12463/clear-the-contents-of-a-permanent-register-or-yank-to-it-without-appending-to-it#comment21646_12463), if you use the lowercase register, i.e. `"t`, it will overwrite instead of append.

You were close with your ex commands to clear the register. However these ones should also be lowercase too. Either of these should work:

```
:call setreg('t', [])
:let @t=''
```

Although I would probably recommend doing

```
:call setreg('t', '')
```

instead of `[]`.